# Using Split function

Tags: python, split

How can I take a dictionary having one key-value pair and split the value as follows-

```
a={"description":"hello,hi,hey,hola"}
```

Now I would like to split the value through second comma and store the two values as(creating a new key-value pair in the dictionary)--

```
a={"description":"hello,hi","kkajan":"hey,hola"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
>>> a_split = a['description'].split(',')
>>> a_list = { 'description' : ','.join(a_split[:2]), 'kkajan' : ','.join(a_split[2:]) }
>>> a_list
{'kkajan': 'hey,hola', 'description': 'hello,hi'}
```

Comment: @kra You are welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.